# How to append a file with a newline using %%writefile -a command in jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter

I use a Jupyter Notebook to write a small program. Therefore, I want to write some cells into a .py file.

I use this magic `%%writefile -a myfile.py`. It works, but the problem is that the content is appended without a new line. So, I have to manually add a line break to `myfile.py` after running the cells.

How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just put an empty line after `%%writefile` in the cell. For example:

```
In [1]: 
%%writefile -a myfile.py

a = 1

In [2]: 
%%writefile -a myfile.py

b = 2
```

Now:

```
In [2]: 
%less myfile.py

a = 1
b = 2
```

Add two empty lines to the beginning of a cell for an empty line between
the exported code of two cells in the file `myfile.py`.